# To what extent do you explain a proof?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

What previous proofs are assumed and which are referenced? Is it based on the target audience of the proof (if that is a thing)? Level's of intuition may also vary drastically, a logical step for one person may need a paragraph of explanation for another.

For example, I can't imagine quoting the definition of a derivative and the standard rules of differentiation, when finding the minimum of a function. In some cases would you even need to show the process, could you just write the minimum?

Comment: This question is rather too broad to have a succinct answer.  But yes, proofs should be written with a particular audience in mind.

Comment: I think that the intended audience does factor into the proof explanation. If it is shown to people with a lower level of math understanding, then more explanation may be required (e.g. for high school students), whereas less explanation is needed if the audience has a high understanding of math (e.g. professors).

Comment: As a general rule for class work, write your proof so that the you of two weeks ago would be able to follow it.

Comment: You're right, you generally wouldn't show the calculation of the minimum of a function. Unless of course, you're writing the proof for students learning about the derivative.

Comment: This very site is a prime example of different proofs for different audiences, even in answers to the same question. It's an important feature of MSE.

Comment: "A proof, that is, a mathematical argument, is a work of fiction, a poem. Its goal is to *satisfy.* A beautiful proof should explain, and it should explain clearly, deeply, and elegantly. A well-written, well-crafted argument should feel like a splash of cool water, and be a beacon of light— it should refresh the spirit and illuminate the mind. And it should be *charming.*" — [A Mathematician's Lament](https://www.maa.org/external_archive/devlin/LockhartsLament.pdf)

Comment: I think the main offense in books and papers is disregarding that inexperienced reader will lack the intuition in this subject. As an undergrad you get used to the bullying of "it can easily be shown/seen that ..." in books. Later stuff just gets left out even without mentioning anything about it. Usually it just seems that the "easily be shown" phrase means "I can prove it but the proof is neither short, nor interesting, nor relevant to the main point."

Comment: I think the main offense in books and papers is disregarding that inexperienced reader will lack the intuition in this subject. As an undergrad you get used to the bullying of "it can easily be shown/seen that ..." in books. Later stuff just gets left out even without mentioning anything about it. Usually it just seems that the "easily be shown" phrase means "I can prove it but the proof is neither short, nor interesting, nor relevant to the main point."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, all proofs are written for a particular audience, each with its own level of expertise and its own peculiar body of knowledge, which may be assumed without explanation. One has to tailor the mathematical writing to the audience. When I give a proof to a graduate seminar, it will look very different than when I give a proof to an undergraduate analysis class, or when I am speaking at a conference of experts.

When writing a mathematics paper for publication, one doesn't always know exactly the audience you will get, and so one should err on the side of extra explanation. A math talk amongst people whose background you know well will be very different.

When I teach a math class and have my students write proofs, then I always tell them to write for the rest of the class as the audience, rather than writing to me. They should explain the things that they think the rest of the class would want explained, and can assume the things that the rest of the class would freely assume along with them.

Comment: I think its so cool that actual professors of math answer questions here

Comment: Even retired professors.

Comment: Someday in the future, when I retire (if I ever retire), I would hope to spend my time answering questions for pleasure here and on MathOverflow. What a great retirement that would be!

Comment: My "proof level suggestion" to students: "write it for the person sitting next to you, who is a very nice person, but not *quite* as smart as you are".